# VBA Sub only works once after edit

Tags: excel, vba

In column A, I have blocks of matching text between which I want to draw borders. The blocks are of different size, so to distinguish between blocks I test if the value of two adjacent cells are different.

First I tried this:

```
Sub draw_borders()


   Dim p As Range, a As Variant, b As Range, c As Range, d As Variant
   For Each p In Intersect(Range("A:A"), sht.UsedRange)
      a = p.Value
      Set c = Range(Cells(p.Row, p.Column), Cells(p.Row, p.Column))
      b = c.Offset(-1, 0)
      d = b.Value
      If a <> d Then
          Dim DataRange3 As Range
          Set DataRange3 = Range(Cells(p.Row, 1), Cells(p.Row, 2))
          DataRange3.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      End If
   Next p
End Sub
```

By the way, "sht" is defined earlier as the active worksheet. I kept getting a runtime error at:

```
b = c.Offset(-1, 0)
```

So I tried to include the offset in the definition of c, deleted the definition of b and edited the definition of d.

```
Sub draw_borders()


   Dim p As Range, a As Variant, b As Range, c As Range, d As Variant
   For Each p In Intersect(Range("A:A"), sht.UsedRange)
      a = p.Value
      Set c = Range(Cells(p.Row, p.Column), Cells(p.Row, p.Column)).Offset(-1,0)

      d = c.Value
      If a <> d Then
          Dim DataRange3 As Range
          Set DataRange3 = Range(Cells(p.Row, 1), Cells(p.Row, 2))
          DataRange3.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      End If
   Next p
End Sub
```

This worked... but only once. If I run it again, it gives me a runtime error at:

```
Set c = Range(Cells(p.Row, p.Column), Cells(p.Row, p.Column)).Offset(-1,0)
```

What is wrong with my code?

I only started learning about vba this week and I don't have any experience in programming, so my formatting might be a bit off.

Comment: With `.Offset(-1,0)`, you are going up one `row` from a given range. I'm thinking you're already at row 1 when the macro tries to go one row up, which results in an error.

Comment: Ah so what you are saying is that, for the first value of p it errors? For the remaining values of p I guess it is OK?

Comment: I just changed the Offset to refer down instead and it worked! Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: If the range `p` were to be in row 1, yes. This is not unlikely given how the loop can be any range within column `A`. Glad to see you figured it out

Comment: A good practice when encountering such errors is using the `F8` key to step through the code. This allows you to see current variable values and figure out the cause of the error.

Comment: I didn't know about that feature. Thank you very much!